# Typescript definition when pulling from dist folder

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to define types for classes when you pull them from a dist folder?

Aka, sometimes I'll do...

```
import MyClass from "dist/classes/myClass.ts";

const instance = new MyClass();
```

How do you write a `.d.ts` file that works for this case too, or is that possible?

Comment: Why would you even need a `.d.ts` file for a TypeScript source file? The compiler should be able to analyze it automatically (unless you explicitly exclude everything under `dist/`, which in this case is probably not ideal). That said, I think you can declare named modules in TypeScript (`declare module "name"`). The name needs to match the import path. Or you could try importing stuff from dist, then reexporting it, then your actual code imports that inbetween import-reexport module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you write a .d.ts file that works for this case too, or is that possible?

Compile with `declaration:true` in `tsconfig.json` and use `types` in your package.json.

## More

Covered in the quickstart: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html